# How do I implement send email to action settings empty activity?

Tags: android, email, android-activity

If user clicks action settings - Send Email to Developer then email apps pop up which are installed to user device. How to do that?

Action settings activity

```
package com.example.kristenungur.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SendEmailtoDev_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendemailtoappdev_layout);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sendemail, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.SendEmail:
            Intent intent = new Intent(SendEmailtoDev_activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way:

```
Intent emailFeedback = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailFeedback.setType("text/email");
emailFeedback.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"your_email_id_here"});
emailFeedback.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailFeedback, "Send Feedback:"));
```

Comment: It gives me errors on my activity? :(. emailfeedback.setType gives me *cannot resolve symbol 'setType' and same with putExtra

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I got it working. I added this to my switch statement so if user clicks the name, email things pop up. Those who use IF statement, just add that statement to there just like in switch statement.

Comment: please don't answer your own question without complete solution.